# Adding controls to custom panel in design window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, user-controls, custom-panel

so I created a custom panel class like `public class CustomPanel : Panel`.
When I double-click it in Solution explorer, its design opens, but its empty (can't see the panel itself, just the text:"To add components to your class, drag them from the toolbox etc...".

Q: What should I do to make my custom component editable in its design window ? Couldn't find anything anywhere..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to design time edit you shoud create `UserControl` instead. (place `Panel` or your custom Panel on it and do whatever you want.. in **DesignMode**)

When you derive (like you described) you just alter or add new methods / properties to `Panel` class and you can use it instead of standard `Panel` class.